# Get Password Log In Form to work when user clicks Enter

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my log in page: http://www.flimpact.org/testlogin.html. The script works perfectly if you enter the password and then click the Login button - a popup alert informs you the password is correct and you move on to the next page. However, if you type the correct password and click Enter instead of clicking the Login in button, you get the alert, but it does NOT forward you to the page.

You can test it yourself - the password is: easy

I've tried changing input type="button" to type="submit" and adding onSubmit="Login()" to my form, but then the form completely stopped working.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Deborah

Comment: Just as a security tip, I wouldn't put any passwords into JavaScript, as it is a rendered on the client-side. Also, you have a syntax error on line 30

Comment: change <input type="button" ... to <input type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're just storing the password client-side for testing purposes?

However, to get your code working, you have a couple of options.  I prefer to use the `logIn` function as a boolean check to determine if it is successful.  Then you need to move the `action` to the `form` and change your button to a `submit` button.  This should work for you:

```
<form name="lform" id="lform" action="http://www.flimpact.org/1staff.html" onSubmit="return logIn()">
    <input type="password" class="passwordinput" size="40" name="login" id="login">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Powered by DCScript
    function logIn() {
        var pass = unescape("%65%61%73%79");
        switch (document.lform.login.value) {
            case pass:
                alert("Valid password. Access granted");
                return true;
                break;
            default:
                alert("Invalid password. Please try again.");
                return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

- [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PaSSR/)

Comment: This works, but viewing the source code shows the URL, making it even less secure than what we started with. Is there a way to encrypt the URL at all?

Comment: @dmwhipp If you're looking for security using javascript on the client side is not where you find it. You'd need to use server side authentication. Check out PHP ([tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/)) and MySQL.

Comment: Thanks... they actually already have server side asp authentication, but want something much simpler to simply keep staff and partners from viewing non-finalized pages. Plus the asp didn't allow them to use the basic password they want. They are fully aware this won't actually be secure. They were actually fine with a simple javascript that actually showed the password in the source code, but I just couldn't handle it being that easy!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can change your "parent.location" to "window.location.href" : )

Answer (score 0):

Try returning false from your logIn() function and changing your form tag to read:

```
<form name="lform" id="lform" onsubmit="return logIn()">
```

Comment: Thanks - since I don't write scripts, I wasn't sure exactly how to return false from my login, but after some trial and error I got it working.

Comment: Is there any way to post the full working code in case anyone else ever needs a low security password protected page?